# Amazon DynamoDB not connecting due to Keystore Exception

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, android-11, amazon-dynamodb

I have an android application to upload some strings to an Amazon DynamoDB table. This application uses cognitoUnauthenticated pools. When I try to connect my application with Amazon DynamoDB, I am getting the following exception

```
E/KeyProvider23: Error in deleting the key for keyAlias: com.amazonaws.android.auth.aesKeyStoreAlias from Android KeyStore.
    java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to delete entry: com.amazonaws.android.auth.aesKeyStoreAlias
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineDeleteEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:879)
        at java.security.KeyStore.deleteEntry(KeyStore.java:1257)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.KeyProvider23.deleteKey(KeyProvider23.java:118)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.AWSKeyValueStore.retrieveEncryptionKey(AWSKeyValueStore.java:493)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.AWSKeyValueStore.get(AWSKeyValueStore.java:226)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:577)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.initialize(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:433)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.<init>(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:195)
        at com.mysample.servicesample.AmazonClientManager.lambda$initClients$0$AmazonClientManager(AmazonClientManager.java:40)
        at com.mysample.servicesample.-$$Lambda$AmazonClientManager$M9LDF0L5OYsIomcIVw0vQmIFrUc.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-09-17 16:42:04.703 22047-22080/com.mysample.servicesample E/AWSKeyValueStore: Error in retrieving the decryption key used to decrypt the data from the persistent store. Returning null for the requested dataKey = us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-pool_Id.identityId
```

Sample code is

```
  private void initClients() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;
        try {
            credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),
                    IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                    Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
            );

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Convo",ex.getMessage());
        }

        ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2));
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a Native Android app that invokes AWS Services, including Amazon DynamoDB, use the AWS SDK for Kotlin. See this AWS tutorial that walks you through how to use this SDK to create an Android app that interacts with DynamoDB.

[Creating your first Native Android application using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/.kotlin_alpha/usecases/first_android_app)